# Using LMDB to implement a sqlite-alike relational database, relevant resources?

Tags: sqlite, relational-database, lmdb

For educational reasons I wish to build a functional, full, relational database. I'm aware LMDB was used to be the storage [backend of sqlite](https://github.com/LMDB/sqlightning), but I don't know C. I'm on .NET and I'm not interested in just duplicate a "traditional" RDBMS (so, for example, I not worry about implement a sql parser but my own custom scripting language that I'm building), but expose the full relational model.

Consider this question similar to "How I implement a programming language on top of LLVM" before worry about why I'm not using sqlite or similar.

From the [material I read](https://schd.ws/hosted_files/buildstuff14/96/20141120-BuildStuff-Lightning.pdf), LMDB look great, specially because It provide transactions and reliability, plus the low-level plumbing. How that translate to changes that could touch several rows at several tables is another question..

Exist material that explain how is implemented a relational layer on top of something like LMDB? Is using LMDB (or their competitors) optimal enough or exist another better way to get results?

Is possible to use LMDB to store other structures like hashtables, arrays and (the one I'm more interested for a columnar database) bitmap arrays?, ie, similar to redis?

P.D: Exist a forum or another place to talk more about this subject?

Answer (score 0):

I had this idea too. You should realize that this is tons of work and most likely no one will care. I haven't built full-blown relational db as this is crazy to do for one person. You could check it out [here](https://github.com/ren85/linqdb)

Anyway I've used leveldb (and later rocksdb) and so you have keys-values sorted by key, ability to get value by key, iterate keys, have atomic writes of many values (WriteBatch) and consistent view of data at given time - snapshots. These features are enough to build correct thread-safe reading of table rows (using snapshots), correct writing of data and related indexes - all or nothing (using writebatch) and even transactions.

Each column has it's on disk index - keys sorted by values - so you could efficiently do various operations on it and keys with values themselves so you  could efficiently read values with given id.

This setup is efficient for writing and reading using available operations on tables with little data (say less than a million rows). However, if table grows iterating over many keys can become not so fast. To solve this and to add a group-by statement I've decided to add memory indexes, but that's another story. So all-in-all it might be fun idea but in reality a lot of work and often frustrating results - why would you want to do that?

Comment: I wanna do this for educational purposes, and also to see how feasible is to archive sqlite-lite functionality for a long project of mine (that also include a relational language). I think exist a lot of ideas for improve the "ergonomics" of use a RDBMS that most are missing.